# loop through each image in div and set variable as a multiple

Tags: jquery, css

I want to loop through all images in a div and set 'left' to be 50px more than the previous image's left setting. I'm having trouble with syntax, though. How do I indicate the i-th img?

html:

```
<div class="col-md-5 leftimage">
        <div class="imageholder">
            <img src="img/photo1.jpg" />
            <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imageholder">
            <img src="img/photo2.jpg" />
            <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imageholder">
            <img src="img/photo3.jpg" />
            <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.leftimage {
    position: relative;

}
.leftimage .imageholder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 300px;
    width: max-content;
}

.imageholder:nth-child(1) {
    /*left: 100px;*/

}
.imageholder:nth-child(2) {
    /*left: 50px;*/

}
.caption {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

jquery:

```
for (var i = 0; i<$('.imageholder img').length; i++) {
    $('.imageholder img')[i].css('left', i*50 + 'px'); //this syntax isn't right
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already using jQuery, it's best to use `.each()` function.

```
$(".leftimage > div").each(function(index){
  $(this).find("img").css("left", index*50 + "px");
});
```

And here's an example:

```js
$(".leftimage > div").each(function(index){
  $(this).find('img').css("left", index*50 + "px");
    $(this).find('.caption').text(index*50 + "px");
});
```

```css
.leftimage {
    position: relative;

}
.leftimage .imageholder {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 300px;
    width: max-content;
}
.leftimage .imageholder img {
    height:100px;
    width:300px;

}

.caption {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftimage">
        <div class="imageholder">
            <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" />
            <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imageholder">
            <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" />
            <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imageholder">
            <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" />
            <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
        </div>
    <div class="imageholder">
            <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" />
            <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works. Thank you! I'll mark it as the answer as soon as the page lets me.

Comment: *"I want to loop through all images in a div and set 'left' to be 50px more than the previous image's left".* **This adds 100px to each subsequent image and not 50px as the OP wanted.**

Comment: @Satwik: I did it this way: $(".imageholder").each(function(index){
   $(this).css("left", index*50 + "px");}); Each imageholder holds an img, so this worked for me.

Comment: @LauraNMS Just using that code and outputting the actual `left` value, watch this: http://jsfiddle.net/7sdp9vz8/. See the value mentioned right below the image.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny You're right, I should have iterated through the direct children. I modified the code in my answer.

Comment: @JackBauer Now, that's correct. Also, if you can, always add an example to make the answer more comprehensible!!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i<$('.imageholder img').length; i++) {
    $($('.imageholder img')[i]).css('left', i*50 + 'px'); //this syntax isn't right
}
```

may do the trick

Comment: This would perform the same query many, many times (once for each `img` in the for loop to reevaluate `.length` and once for each `[i]`). Also, including an explanation of why the code you are proposing will fix the OP's question would be a good idea, as SO is for everyone, not just the OP.